# How to change the font for only the first "Column name" pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda Dataframe with 3 columns. I need to change the font for only the First 'Column name' and have the 2nd and the 3rd column names to be of a different font. I'm using render function to generate the CSS tags.

i tried to use the df.style.set_table_styles function but it applies the same font to all the column names ( column headers).

Is there a way to limit the application of style function to only first column header?

```py
df.style.set_table_styles
df.style.set_properties(subset=df.columns[0], **{'text-align':'left','font-family': 'Courier','font-size': '10px'})

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
               'B':[4,5,6],
               'C':[7,8,9],
               'D':[1,3,5],
               'E':[5,3,6],
               'F':[7,4,3]})
df=df.style.set_properties(subset=df.columns[0], **{'text-align':'left','font-family': 'Cambria','font-size': '10px'})
print(df.render())
```

i want only 'A' to have a Cambria font and the rest ( B,C,D etc.) to have a different font.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use some CSS trickery to select the first column header:

```
def set_header_font():
    return [dict(selector="th:nth-child(2)",
                 props=[("font-size", "14pt"),("font-family", 'Cambria')])]

df.style.set_table_styles(set_header_font())
```

The `nth-child(2)` selects the second `th` element in your table --- second `th` because the first `th` is used for your DataFrame index name (which is an empty string in your case).